# why is xargs producing {} sometimes?

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a file that looks like this:

```
3839440388|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: {.job_code} Failed to add JDBC connection to the connection pool, connection pool is full..
126216303|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: BIP job failed
2651334677|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: Failure during Schedule Item Import job..
2952592408|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
719205600|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: oracle.xdo.servlet.CreateException
1495326131|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Transfered zip file failed validation
3069376900|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Spawned job for request {.request_id} produced the business error exit code: BIZ_ERROR
2503345575|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Could not update entity indexing state for entity with uuid: '{.uuid}' in meta model version with uuid '{.uuid}': method [PUT], host
2184383281|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.JRFSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server
3847951072|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: <env:Body xmlns:env=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>
```

I am trying to do the following:

1. take the second part of this pipe delimited file and
2. produce a file of `${char_count}|${message}`
3. Then find the largest message with `sort -nr | tail -1`

Here is the command I ran:

```
cut -d'|' -f2 cksum.psv | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'printf "%d|%s\n" $(echo "${1}" | wc -c) "${1}"' _ {}
```

But, it occasionally produces a `{}` which I don't understand:

Output:

```
3|{}
206|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: BIP job failed
231|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: Failure during Schedule Item Import job..
222|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
226|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: oracle.xdo.servlet.CreateException
89|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Transfered zip file failed validation
138|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Spawned job for request {.request_id} produced the business error exit code: BIZ_ERROR
184|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: Could not update entity indexing state for entity with uuid: '{.uuid}' in meta model version with uuid '{.uuid}': method [PUT], host
3|{}
254|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a business error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: <env:Body xmlns:env=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/>
```

Why is it producing an occassional `{}`.
If I leaved off `-I {}` then I only get 1 line of output:

```
281|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: {.job_code} Failed to add JDBC connection to the connection pool, connection pool is full..
```

Comment: What's the point of `-I {}` here? If you just leave it off, the things xargs finds populate `$1` and on, so you can make your shell scriptlet loop over them (in a single shell instance, instead of eating the performance hit of starting a separate shell executable per item).

Comment: You can also count characters much, _much_ more quickly with `str=$1; str_len=${#str}`; that way you're relying only on shell builtins instead of needing to fork a subprocess to run the `echo` and a second subprocess to exec `wc -c`

Comment: (really, though, this is a job that awk would perform much better at overall).

Comment: Anyhow -- which operating system's xargs do you have? If you have the GNU one, notice the `-r` / `--no-run-if-empty` extension. That's a typical place to need to nose around for a problem that only happens occasionally / depending on how items are on xargs' stdin, though I don't have time right now to track down how the problem that triggers it would behave with your code.

Comment: BTW -- concretely, what do the lines in your input `.psv` file that correspond to the error look like? (Arguably, that information _needs_ to be included to have a proper [mre])

Comment: I did say if you leave off `-I {}` that you need to make your scriptlet loop. You can't only make half the change that's suggested to you and expect it to work.

Comment: `xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'for arg; do printf "%d|%s\n" "${#arg}" "$arg"; done' _` -- time it against your answer; you'll see it's _far_ faster.

Comment: Thank you for all the input. It doesn't explain the `{}`, which I sometimes see in other situations. But I have a working solution, Thank you for the idea to use the shell built in

Comment: (btw, there are concrete correctness reasons to prefer `printf` over `echo`, _especially_ when you're using `sh` instead of `bash`: the POSIX spec lets a compliant `sh` implement `echo` a wide variety of ways, including ways that interpret escape sequences by default; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing the entirety of the pipeline with the following:

```
while IFS='|' read -r _ data _; do
  printf '%d|%s\n' "${#data}" "$data"
done <cksum.psv
```

That way we're invoking no external tools at all and keeping all the logic inside your shell.

- `IFS='|' read -r _ data _` discards the first column (by putting it into the variable `_`) and the third column and onward (by putting *those* into `_`), and puts the second column into `data`. Using `IFS='|'` makes it split on pipes; using `-r` prevents backslashes from being treated as syntax rather than data during `read`'s operation.
- `printf '%d|%s\n' "${#data}" "$data"` has several moving parts:

  - `${#data}` expands to the length of the content of `data`
  - `"$data"` expands to the precise content of the data variable (being in double quotes, suppressing word-splitting and glob expansion).
- `<cksum.psv` redirects stdin for the duration of the `while read` loop.

Comment: Great breakdown. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't answer my original question as to why I get `{}` sometimes, but it does produced the desired results:

```
cut -d'|' -f2 cksum.psv | tr '\n' '\0' | 
xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'echo "${#1}|${1}"' _ | sort -t '|' -n  | tail -1
280|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: {.job_code} Failed to add JDBC connection to the connection pool, connection pool is full..
```

Comment: This is _really_ unnecessarily slow -- it's going to spend more time having xargs start up a new copy of `sh` for every line of content than it spends doing anything else at all.

Comment: ...and for that matter, you don't need `xargs` or `sh` at all. Consider `while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do printf '%d|%s\n' "${#line}" "$line"; done` as a complete replacement for the xargs line as a whole, assuming your outer interpreter is bash. (Even that is slow compared to equivalent awk logic, as bash reads one byte at a time, but it's far faster than making xargs invoke a process per line)

Comment: To explain why I'm pushing you on this: Stack Overflow is intended to be a learning resource; answers aren't just to fix the OP's immediate problem, but also to help inform the practices of everyone who reads the question and its answers in the future. As such, we have a responsibility to showcase good practices; being cavalier about using practices with major performance impact is a large factor in why major distros have switched away from using shells at init time; I'm not saying a POSIXy shell is ever _fast_, but there's orders of magnitude between scripts that are carefully written and not

Comment: My question wasn't at all about performance, though I do appreciate some of the improvements you suggested. My question was why I am seeing `{}`, which still isn't answered. One of the challenges I have with SoF is that I ask a specific thing and people get sidetracked with critiquing my approach, even if that's entirely warranted. Code review stack exchange is for that and, maybe I will post my sample there and see how it can be improved. Thank you again